# want to get a row from cursor

Tags: android

I want to get a row and this row have 2 columns which named `username` and `password` my code is here:

```
String selection = PROFILE_COLUMN_USERNAME + " = '" + userName+ "' AND " +PROFILE_COLUMN_PASSWORD + " = '" + password + "'";
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {PROFILE_COLUMN_USERNAME, PROFILE_COLUMN_PASSWORD }, selection,null, null, null, null);
```

I got a sample data like `username = erdem` and `password= c` on my db but when i write this sample and write to get `username`  like this:

```
String s =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PROFILE_COLUMN_USERNAME));
```

it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below : Here "path_on_server" is the name of the column in the DB table whose value is being extracted. You can change it to your table's column name.

```
        String query = "some query";
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    mPathOnServer = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex("path_on_server"));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException se) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Could not extract information from DB");
    }
```

Comment: A little tip: the two `if`s are not necessary just use `if( c != null && c.moveToFirst() ){ ... }`, if is c is null moveToFirst won't be called.

Comment: i m new abou android. Thanks for reply but mPathOnServer means?

Comment: Its just the name of a variable wherein I am storing the value of a column from one of the tables in my app's database..

Comment: if PROFILE_COLUMN_USERNAME is your actual column name in the table put that in double quotes when you do the getColumnIndex

Comment: it worked thanks. i found my mistake. want to rate your answer but my reputation doesn't allow this:)

Comment: Just accept it as answer... Use the tick symbol across my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `moveToFirst`, [read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
Cursor cursor = null;

try {
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name";

    cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery(queryString, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    String nextUser = new String(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("driver_fname")));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.deactivate();
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
            if (myDatabase != null) {
                myDatabase.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: i can list my data using SELECT * FROM Table_Name query but when i try to my query at question it doesnt work. may be a mistake at my query?